# Angular: observe two states but only act once

Tags: angular, rxjs

My component observes two states (in observable stores): `selectedCar` and `viewConfig`. When either of these states updates, I need to run `showCar()` to display the car with the new config. However, when both of these states update, e.g. on init, `showCar()` should only run once.

Code below:

```js
    this.selectedCarStore.state$
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
      .subscribe(state => {
        this.selectedCar = state.selectedCar;
        this.showCar();
      });

    this.configStore.state$
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
      .subscribe(_state => {
        this.viewConfig = state.viewConfig;
        this.showCar();
      });
    
    showCar() {
      if (this.viewConfig != null || this.selectedCar != null) return;

      // update UI with selected car and view config
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The displaying of your `car` has two sources: `selectedCar` and `viewConfig`.  We can design an observable that will emit only when both of these data are available AND whenever either of them change.  The [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) operator is perfect for this:

So now, instead of having two separate subscriptions, we just have one!

```js
ngOnInit() {
  combineLatest([
    this.selectedCarStore.state$, 
    this.configStore.state$]
  ).pipe(
    takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
  )
  .subscribe(([carState, config]) => {
    this.allCars     = carState.allCars;
    this.selectedCar = carState.selectedCar;
    this.viewConfig  = config.viewConfig;
    this.showCar();
  });
}
```

The above code in the `subscribe` block will only emit when both `selectedCarStore.state$` and `configStore.state$` have emitted at least once.

Check out this working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66551589-solution?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts);  See how the view is updated when you select different View Config or select a different car.

This accomplishes your goal... but we can make the code even better (simpler)!

---

If we take a look at your comment for the `showCar()` method:

```
// update UI with selected car and view config
```

It sort of hints at the fact that we weren't previously structuring the code in a declarative / reactive way.  Now that we have designed a stream that emits when we want, with all the necessary data, we don't need to "manually" check in a function to update the view.  Our view will update automatically, because our stream emits at the appropriate time.  Any time either of the sources emit a new value, the view will automatically be updated! :-)

Notice how we are copying state into our component:

```js
this.allCars     = carState.allCars;
this.selectedCar = carState.selectedCar;
this.viewConfig  = config.viewConfig;
```

This actually isn't necessary. Instead of subscribing in our component, we can leave all the data the view needs as observables.  So instead of:

```js
public viewConfig: ViewConfig;
public selectedCar: Car;
public allCars: Car[];
```

We can do:

```js
  private viewConfig$ = this.configStore.state$.pipe(
    map(state => state.viewConfig)
  );
  private selectedCar$ = this.selectedCarStore.state$.pipe(
    map(state => state.selectedCar)
  );
  public selectedCarVm$ = combineLatest([this.selectedCar$, this.viewConfig$]).pipe(
    map(([car, config]) => ({car, config}))
  );
  public allCars$ = this.selectedCarStore.state$.pipe(
    map(state => state.allCars)
  );
```

The `public` ones are what the view needs.  I used the `Vm` suffix to distinguish between the data for `selectedCar` and the view model we designed to only emit when both the data and config are available.

Notice, we define these observable streams right on our class, we no longer need to do this in `ngOnInit`.  We also no longer need to subscribe, as we can use the `async` pipe in our template.

```html
  <div *ngIf="selectedCarVm$ | async as selected"
    [ngStyle]="{'background-color': selected.config.bgColor }"
    [class.large]="selected.config.size === 'large'"
  >
    {{ selected.car.year }} {{ selected.car.make }} {{ selected.car.model }}
  </div>
```

The means we no longer need to manage unsubscribing, so we can get rid of `ngOnDestroy`, the `ngUnsubscribe` Subject as well as all our `takeUntil`s!

Please compare code between your [Original Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66551589-original) > the [First Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66551589-solution) > and this [Reactive Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66551589-solution-reactive?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Each step reduces the code and simplifies the logic.

I hope this helps to show you how you can design streams to emit at the desired time, and keep the data in observable form in order to reduce the amount of code (and complexity).

Cheers! :-)

Comment: This answer is the right one but it's too long. First paragraph and component snippet + template `async` pipe should suffice for what the OP is requesting.

Btw. Nice job +1

Comment: Thanks brother.  Yeah it did get a bit long-winded.. but hey... I did put a line break in there :-)

Comment: Thanks. Excellent answer and `combineLatest` does indeed what I expected (but I think its naming is funny). I'm actually very grateful for the second part too. Although in this case I'm not actually updating a UI but rather using the state data to make HTTP calls. That probably doesn't work then. There may be a case for injecting the State into the HTTP service instead but I'm not quite sure if that's efficient.

Answer (score 0):

> when both of these states update

Given the single thread nature of JavaScript, the states would never update simultaneously. Once you understand that, your problem becomes one of resolution.
i.e, "when both of these states update within x time units of the other"

You may use operators like [throttleTime](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/throttleTime) and [auditTime](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/auditTime) after merging both with [merge](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/merge) to solve.

Comment: `debounceTime` would be another canonical candidate here.